# Python: Never entering if statement for conversion

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop

I have an list which tells me which columns need to be converted from bytes into KB.

```
covert_to_kb_columns=[9, 10, 21, 22, 24]
```

I am having trouble implementing my code correctly. I want to check that if I am on the an `'idx'` number that matches one of the numbers in the
`covert_to_kb_columns` list than I should preform the calculation otherwise leave the number as is. The `try/except` statement is for when there is 
no number in the file just a '', so I append a zero.

```
print covert_to_kb_columns
for idx, column_number in enumerate(columns_I_am_working_with):
    print idx
    #Check if I need to convert number from bytes to KB
    if idx == [number for number in covert_to_kb_columns]:
        print "Need to divide by 1024.0"
        data_to_use.append("{:.1f}".format(float(row[column_number]) / 1024.0))
    #Otherwise just append number as is
    else:
        try:
            float(row[column_number])
            data_to_use.append(row[column_number])
        except ValueError:
            data_to_use.append('0')
```

My print statements give me this result: (Note '.' is to indicate that all numbers were printed but I'm not writing them all 39 numbers out )

```
[9, 10, 21, 22, 24]
0
1
2
3
.
.
.
9
10
.
.
.
21
22
23
24
.
.
.
39
```

It seems that it never enters the print statement to perform the conversion. 
I think the issue is with the line

```
if idx == [number for number in covert_to_kb_columns]:
```

But I can't spot what I doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`idx == [number for number in covert_to_kb_columns]` checks if the index is equal to a list containing all of the elements of `covert_to_kb_columns`. It's the same as `idx == covert_to_kb_columns`.

All you need to do is `idx in covert_to_kb_columns`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` condition is **false**. The right is:

```
if idx in covert_to_kb_columns:
```

`[number for number in covert_to_kb_columns]` build a new list from your list `covert_to_kb_columns`. And they are identical. It is useless here.

And with `idx == [number for number in covert_to_kb_columns]` you are comparing a index number with a list. This condition returns always the value `false`